# Audiobooks to Hear Porteño (Buenos Aires) Accent

Tags: argentina

What would be some good audiobooks to hear an authentic Porteño (Buenos Aires native) accent?  I've looked through quite a few sites but haven't found anything yet.

Comment: These aren't all voiced by Porteño actors, but the ones I have sampled are interesting and all of them are free:  https://www.argentina.gob.ar/cultura/publicaciones/audiolibros

Comment: Try Netflix. There are several soap operas from Argentina. By the way, it's the accent but above all the verb usages.

Answer (score 1):

Not audiobooks but If you pick a tv show from Argentina, you are most likely going to listen to porteños talking. The reason is that most of the media consumed in Argentina is originated in Buenos Aires.

Comment: Also: https://venganzasdelpasado.com.ar/